# How to achieve different types on joins with LINQ..?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

On Sql server we have multiple joins viz. left outer join, right outer join, full outer join, self join

Can anyone given an example for each on LINQ..? And how to achieve the same result with Extension methods...?

Comment: You may want to check out the LINQ Samples provided by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688085.aspx  It has a couple of these, but lots of other LINQ examples great for getting started/quick reference as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a nice article with examples which shows [SQL joins with LINQ](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C#-LINQ.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one of the best ways to learn how to convert SQL to Linq-To-SQL is via a product named Linqer. It will convert most any SQL into L2S. It's not free, about $50. But it comes with a 30 day trial period. You can generate a lot of queries in 30 days.

```
http://www.sqltolinq.com/home
```